# proving $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$ in a $\mathbb Z$-graded integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings, graded-modules

In a $\mathbb Z$-graded integral domain $B = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} B_i$ my definition for the degree function is as follows:

Given $f \in B,$ define $\deg : B \rightarrow \mathbb Z \cup \{-\infty \}$ by $$\deg(f) = \mathrm{maxSupp}{(f)} \text{ if } f \neq 0 \text{ and } \deg(0) = -\infty $$

My definition for the  $\mathrm{Supp}$ of $f$ is as follows $\{i \in \mathbb Z| f_i \neq 0\}.$

Here is the statement I want to prove:

$\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g).$

Here is my trial:

Let $f = f_0 + f_1 + \dots +f_k \neq 0$ where $f_i \in B_i, 0 \leq i \leq k, f_k \neq 0, \deg(f) = k$ and let $g = g_0 + g_1 + \dots +g_l \neq 0$ where $g_j \in B_j, 0 \leq j \leq l, g_l \neq 0, \deg(g) = l.$

Now, $\deg(fg) = \deg ((\sum_{i = 0}^k f_i)(\sum_{j = 0}^l g_j)) = \deg (\sum_{n=0}^{l+k} \sum_{i + j = n, i \geq 0, j \geq 0} f_i g_i)$ and $f_lg_k \neq 0 \implies \deg (fg) = l + k = \deg(f) +  \deg(g)$ this is because we are in an integral domain.

If either $f$ or $g$ is $0,$ then $fg = 0$ and so $\deg(fg) = -\infty = \deg(f) + \deg(g) = -\infty$

But I think that my trial has 2 mistakes which are:

1- I took $i,j$ starting from $0.$ even though according to the support I defined above they should be in $\mathbb Z.$ How can I correct the proof to include $i,j$ as integers?

2- I think I used that I have $\mathbb Z$-graded integral domain $B$ in the wrong place. Could anyone help me in correcting this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about $(1)$, this does not cover all cases. I don't think $(2)$ is right though, you *are* using that $B$ is a domain and $\mathbb{Z}$-graded correctly. You just have to adapt the proof to the general case.

To do that, prove (or use) that
$$
\left(\sum_{i=m}^ka_i\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=n}^l b_j\right) = \sum_{s = m+n }^{k+l}\left(\sum_{i+j=s} a_ib_j\right)
$$

for any $m \leq k, n \leq l$.

Comment: So this is the only mistake in my proof?

Comment: Is it correct because we are in a domain that $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$ even if the degree took integer values?

Comment: Yes, as  in your previous question: if the general case seems too abstract, try some examples first. A canonical one is the ring of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[t.t^{-1}]$. E.g. $\deg(1+t^{-28}+t) = 1$ and $\deg(11t^{-10}-3t^{-2}) = -2$ thus 
$$
(t^{-28}+1+t)(11t^{-10}-3t^{-2}) = 11t^{-38}-3t^{-30}+11t^{-10}+11t^{-9}-3t^{-2}+t^{-1}.
$$
has degree $-1$.

Comment: I did not understand why the degree of your first Laurant polynomial is $1,$ could you explain please?

Comment: The grading is defined by setting $B_n = \{k \cdot t^n : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. So homogeneous elements of degree $n$ (i.e elements of $B_n$) are integer multiples of $t^n$. Hence for example $200043 \cdot t^{-22}$ has degree $-22$, and $t$ has degree $1$. Since $t^0 = 1$, integers have degree zero.

Comment: Should not it be $-27$ ?

Comment: Since $1 \in B_0, t^{-28} \in B_{-28}$ and $t \in B_1$, we have $\deg(1+t^{-28}+t) = \max\{0,1,-28\} = 1$.

Comment: oh I see thank you!